# PDF/A: How to spot the missing glyph?

Tags: fonts, pdf-a

I am trying to have my rendered PDF validate as PDF/A. It fails with the error message that `The glyph for character 0 in font ... is missing.`

Visually inspecting the document, I find no obvious missing glyphs. How can I pinpoint the exact location in the document? A cursory glance at he log file did not help. (I am using `LuaLaTeX`, in case that's important.)

Comment: Check if the log reports missing characters.

Comment: I double-checked the log, and buried in line 5,000 or thereabouts I found the relevant „Missing character“ entry I had missed the first time. This clears up the error, thank you.